# JSF - Autocomplete Feature For Select Boxes Without Hitting Server

Tags: jquery, json, jsf, jsf-2

I am pretty new to client side development. Though there might be some solutions already available. Let me try to describe my problem scenario. I have a `JSF page` (form) where different drops downs(select boxes) are present. They can be of nationality, language or religion. When we enter code, it selects the nationality or language. In this basically a `server hit goes(partial ajax request)`. My senior has advised me to develop this `auto-complete` feature completely client side.  They don't want any server hit for that.

What they basically they want is, when i enter some value, it loads the suggestion list from the client end, it shouldn't go to the server. It should than `update the jsf component` accordingly? How can i approach this problem? Any suggestions are helpful.

**CURRENT PROJECT BASE HAS THIS CODE - CUSTOM COMPONENT**

```
public class VisionSelectOneMenuRenderer extends InputRenderer {
  @Override
  public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    VisionSelectOneMenu menu = (VisionSelectOneMenu) component;

    if (menu.isDisabled() || menu.isReadonly()) {
      return;
    }

    decodeBehaviors(context, menu);

    String clientId = menu.getClientId(context);
    String value = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(clientId + "_selectBox");

    if (value != null) {
      menu.setSubmittedValue(value);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    VisionSelectOneMenu menu = (VisionSelectOneMenu) component;

    encodeMarkup(context, menu);
    encodeScript(context, menu);
  }

  protected void encodeMarkup(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu) throws IOException {
    List<SelectItem> selectItems = getSelectItems(context, menu);
    String clientId = menu.getClientId(context);
    boolean disabled = menu.isDisabled();
    Class type = getValueType(context, menu);

    String styleclass = menu.getStyleClass();
    styleclass = styleclass == null ? VisionSelectOneMenu.STYLE_CLASS : VisionSelectOneMenu.STYLE_CLASS + " " + styleclass;
    styleclass = disabled ? styleclass + " ui-state-disabled" : styleclass;
    styleclass = "sfield";

    /* writer.startElement("div", menu);
writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId, "id");
writer.writeAttribute("class", styleclass, "styleclass");
if(style != null)
writer.writeAttribute("style", style, "style");    */

    encodeInput(context, menu, clientId, selectItems, type);
    //encodeLabel(context, menu, selectItems, type);
    //encodeMenuIcon(context, menu);
    // encodePanel(context, menu, selectItems, type);

    // writer.endElement("div");
  }

  protected void encodeInput(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, String clientId, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String inputId = clientId + "_selectBox";

    writer.startElement("div", menu);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", "sfield", null);

    writer.startElement("select", menu);
    writer.writeAttribute("id", inputId, "id");
    writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", "-1", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", inputId, null);
    //writer.writeAttribute("class", "searchableSelectLookupSelect", null);
    if (menu.getOnchange() != null) {
      writer.writeAttribute("onchange", menu.getOnchange(), null);
    }
    if (menu.isDisabled()) {
      writer.writeAttribute("disabled", "disabled", null);
    }

    encodeSelectItems(context, menu, selectItems, type);

    writer.endElement("select");

    writer.startElement("input", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId, null);
    //writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", "-1", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("name", clientId, null);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", "searchableSelectLookupText excludeClear", null);
    if (menu.isDisabled()) {
        writer.writeAttribute("disabled", "disabled", null);
    }
    writer.endElement("input");

    writer.endElement("div");
  }

  protected void encodeLabel(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String label = getSelectedLabel(context, menu, selectItems, type);

    writer.startElement("a", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("href", "#", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.LABEL_CONTAINER_CLASS, null);

    if (menu.getTabindex() != null) {
      writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", menu.getTabindex(), null);
    }

    writer.startElement("label", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.LABEL_CLASS, null);

    if (label.equals("&nbsp;")) {
      writer.write(label);
    }
    else {
      writer.writeText(label, null);
    }

    writer.endElement("label");
    writer.endElement("a");
  }

  protected void encodeMenuIcon(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

    writer.startElement("div", menu);
    //writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.TRIGGER_CLASS, null);

    writer.startElement("span", menu);
    //writer.writeAttribute("class", "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s", null);
    writer.endElement("span");

    writer.endElement("div");
  }

  protected void encodePanel(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    boolean customContent = menu.getVar() != null;
    int height = calculatePanelHeight(menu, selectItems.size());

    writer.startElement("div", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("id", menu.getClientId(context) + "_panel", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.PANEL_CLASS, null);

    if (height != -1) {
      writer.writeAttribute("style", "height:" + height + "px", null);
    }

    if (customContent) {
      writer.startElement("table", menu);
      writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.TABLE_CLASS, null);
      writer.startElement("tbody", menu);
      encodeOptionsAsTable(context, menu, selectItems, type);
      writer.endElement("tbody");
      writer.endElement("table");
    }
    else {
      writer.startElement("ul", menu);
      writer.writeAttribute("class", VisionSelectOneMenu.LIST_CLASS, null);
      encodeOptionsAsList(context, menu, selectItems, type);
      writer.endElement("ul");
    }

    writer.endElement("div");
  }

  protected void encodeOptionsAsTable(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String var = menu.getVar();
    List<Column> columns = menu.getColums();
    Object value = menu.getValue();

    for (SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
      Object itemValue = selectItem.getValue();
      Object coercedItemValue = null;

      if (itemValue != null && !itemValue.equals("")) {
        coercedItemValue = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().coerceToType(itemValue, type);
      }

      boolean selected = (value != null && value.equals(coercedItemValue));

      context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put(var, selectItem.getValue());

      String rowStyleClass = selected ? VisionSelectOneMenu.ROW_CLASS + " ui-state-active" : VisionSelectOneMenu.ROW_CLASS;

      writer.startElement("tr", null);
      writer.writeAttribute("class", rowStyleClass, null);

      if (itemValue instanceof String) {
        writer.startElement("td", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("colspan", columns.size(), null);
        writer.write(selectItem.getLabel());
        writer.endElement("td");
      }
      else {
        for (Column column : columns) {
          writer.startElement("td", null);
          column.encodeAll(context);
          writer.endElement("td");
        }
      }

      writer.endElement("tr");
    }

    context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put(var, null);
  }

  protected void encodeOptionsAsList(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    Object value = menu.getValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectItems.size(); i++) {
      SelectItem selectItem = selectItems.get(i);
      Object itemValue = selectItem.getValue();
      String itemLabel = selectItem.getLabel();
      Object coercedItemValue = null;
      itemLabel = isValueBlank(itemLabel) ? "&nbsp;" : itemLabel;

      if (itemValue != null && !itemValue.equals("")) {
        coercedItemValue = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().coerceToType(itemValue, type);
      }

      boolean selected = (i == 0 && value == null) || (value != null && value.equals(coercedItemValue));
      String itemStyleClass = selected ? VisionSelectOneMenu.ITEM_CLASS + " ui-state-active" : VisionSelectOneMenu.ITEM_CLASS;

      writer.startElement("li", null);
      writer.writeAttribute("class", itemStyleClass, null);

      if (itemLabel.equals("&nbsp;")) {
        writer.write(itemLabel);
      }
      else {
        writer.writeText(itemLabel, null);
      }

      writer.endElement("li");
    }
  }

  protected void encodeScript(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu) throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = menu.getClientId(context);

    writer.startElement("script", null);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", null);
    //writer.write("var selectedText = '';");

    // TEXT box script
    //writer.write("jQuery(document).ready(function(){$('#"+clientId+"').val($('#"+clientId+"_selectBox option:selected').text());});" +
    writer.write(
        "jQuery(document).ready(function(){" +
            //" if($('#"+clientId+"_selectBox').is(':disabled')){ $('#"+clientId+"').attr('disabled','disabled') }" +
            "$('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').focus(function(){" +
            //"if(!$('#"+clientId+"_selectBox').is(':hover')){"+
            // " $('#"+clientId+"').val(''); $('#"+clientId+"').focus();} "+
            "});" +
            "$('#" + clientId + "').val($('#" + clientId + "_selectBox option:selected').text());" +
            /*"$('#"+clientId+"_selectBox option').each(function(){" +
        //"var idvalue = $(this).text().split('$')[0];" +
        "var level = $(this).text().split(' [')[0];" +
        "var levelCode = $(this).text().split(' [')[1];" +
        "var desc = level.concat('^');" +

        "if(null != levelCode && typeof(levelCode)!='undefined' && levelCode.length > 0) {" +
          "var subStr = levelCode.substring(0,3);" +
          "desc = desc.concat(levelCode.substring(0,levelCode.length-1));" +

          "$(this).attr('description',desc);" +
        "}"+

        //"$(this).attr('description',$(this).text());" +
        //"$(this).text(idvalue);" +
        "$('#"+clientId+"').val($('#"+clientId+"_selectBox option:selected').text());" +
        "}" +
        ")});" +*/

            "jQuery('#" + clientId + "').keyup(" +
            "function(event){ " +
            "if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 9) { " +
            "var enteredText = $('#" + clientId + "').val();" +
            "$('#" + clientId + "_selectBox > option').each(function(){" +
            "   var optionValue = $(this).val();" +
            "   var optionText = $(this).text();" +
            "   var optionDesc = $(this).attr('description');" +
            "   if(optionValue == enteredText) {" +
            "     $('#" + clientId + "').val(optionText);" +
            "     $('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').val(optionValue);" +
            "   }" +
            "   if(optionValue != 0) {" +
            "       var splitted = optionDesc.split('^');" +
            "       if(splitted[1] == enteredText.toUpperCase()) {" +
            "         $('#" + clientId + "').val(optionText);" +
            "         $('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').val(optionValue);" +
            "       }" +
            "   }" +
            " " +
            "});" +
            "}" +// if for keycode ends
            "});"
    );

    writer.write(
        "jQuery('#" + clientId + "').click(" +
            "function(){" +
            "$('#" + clientId + "').val('');" +
            "});"
    );


    /*writer.write("jQuery('#"+clientId+"').focus(" +
        "function(){" +
        "$('#"+clientId+"_selectBox').trigger('click');" +
        "});"
    );*/

    writer.write(
        "jQuery('#" + clientId + "').blur(" +
            "function(){" +
            "var enteredText = $('#" + clientId + "').val();" +
            "$('#" + clientId + "_selectBox > option').each(function(){" +
            "   var optionValue = $(this).val();" +
            "   var optionText = $(this).text();" +
            "   var optionDesc = $(this).attr('description');" +
            "   if(optionValue == enteredText) {" +
            "     $('#" + clientId + "').val(optionText);" +
            "     $('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').val(optionValue);" +
            "     jQuery('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').trigger('change'); " +
            "   }" +
            "   if(optionValue != 0) {" +
            "       var splitted = optionDesc.split('^');" +
            "       if(splitted[1] == enteredText.toUpperCase()) {" +
            "         $('#" + clientId + "').val(optionText);" +
            "         $('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').val(optionValue);  jQuery('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').trigger('change');" +
            "       }" +
            "   }" +
            " " +
            "});" +
            "       $('#" + clientId + "').val($('#" + clientId + "_selectBox option:selected').text());" +
            "});"
    );


    //writer.write("jQuery('#"+clientId+"_selectBox').onmouseover(this.size=this.length)");

    encodeClientBehaviors(context, menu);

    writer.endElement("script");
  }


  protected void encodeClientBehaviors(FacesContext context, ClientBehaviorHolder component) throws IOException {
    String script = "";
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = ((UIComponent) component).getClientId(context);


    //ClientBehaviors
    Map<String, List<ClientBehavior>> behaviorEvents = component.getClientBehaviors();

    if (!behaviorEvents.isEmpty()) {

      List<ClientBehaviorContext.Parameter> params = Collections.emptyList();

      for (Iterator<String> eventIterator = behaviorEvents.keySet().iterator(); eventIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String event = eventIterator.next();

        for (Iterator<ClientBehavior> behaviorIter = behaviorEvents.get(event).iterator(); behaviorIter.hasNext(); ) {
          ClientBehavior behavior = behaviorIter.next();
          ClientBehaviorContext cbc = ClientBehaviorContext.createClientBehaviorContext(
              context,
              (UIComponent) component,
              event,
              clientId,
              params
          );
          script += behavior.getScript(cbc);    //could be null if disabled
        }
      }
    }

    // SELECT Box scripts
    writer.write(
        "jQuery('#" + clientId + "_selectBox').change(" +
            "function(){" +
            "var selectedValue = $('#" + clientId + "_selectBox option:selected').text();" +
            "     $('#" + clientId + "').val(selectedValue);" + script +
            "}" +
            ");});"
    );
  }

  protected void encodeSelectItems(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems, Class type)
      throws IOException {
    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    Converter converter = getConverter(context, menu);
    Object value = menu.getValue();

    for (SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
      Object itemValue = selectItem.getValue();
      String itemLabel = selectItem.getLabel();
      String tLabel = itemLabel;

      if (itemValue != null && !itemValue.equals("")) {
        itemValue = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().coerceToType(itemValue, type);
      }

      writer.startElement("option", null);
      writer.writeAttribute("description", tLabel, null);
      writer.writeAttribute("value", getOptionAsString(context, menu, converter, itemValue), null);


      if (value != null && value.equals(itemValue)) {
        writer.writeAttribute("selected", "selected", null);
      }

      //if((Long)itemValue != 0) {
      /*if((Long)itemValue == 209) {
        writer.write(itemLabel + " [AFG]");
      } else if((Long)itemValue == 203) {
        writer.write(itemLabel + " [PAK]");
      } else if((Long)itemValue == 205) {
        writer.write(itemLabel + " [IND]");
      } else {
        writer.write(itemLabel + " [" + itemValue + "]");
      }*/
      /*}
      else
        writer.write(itemLabel);*/

      //writer.write(itemLabel);
      if (itemLabel.contains("^")) {
        String[] formattedLabel = itemLabel.split("\\^");

        itemLabel = formattedLabel[0] + " [" + formattedLabel[1] + "]" + " [" + itemValue + "]";
        writer.write(itemLabel);
      }
      else {
        if (itemValue instanceof Long) {
          if ((Long) itemValue != 0) {
            writer.write(itemLabel + " [" + itemValue + "]");
          }
          else {
            writer.write(itemLabel);
          }
        }
        else {
          writer.write(itemLabel);
        }
      }

      writer.endElement("option");
    }
  }

  protected String getSelectedLabel(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> items, Class type) {
    Object value = menu.getValue();
    String label = null;

    for (SelectItem item : items) {
      Object itemValue = item.getValue();
      if (itemValue != null && !itemValue.equals("")) {
        itemValue = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().coerceToType(item.getValue(), type);
      }

      if (value != null && value.equals(itemValue)) {
        label = item.getLabel();
        break;
      }
    }

    if (label == null) {
      label = !items.isEmpty() ? items.get(0).getLabel() : "&nbsp;";
    }

    return label;
  }

  protected int calculatePanelHeight(VisionSelectOneMenu menu, int itemSize) {
    int height = menu.getHeight();

    if (height != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      return height;
    }
    else if (itemSize > 10) {
      return 200;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeChildren(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    //Rendering happens on encodeEnd
  }

  @Override
  public boolean getRendersChildren() {
    return true;
  }

  protected Class getValueType(FacesContext context, VisionSelectOneMenu menu) {
    ValueExpression ve = menu.getValueExpression("value");
    Class type = ve == null ? String.class : ve.getType(context.getELContext());

    return type == null ? String.class : type;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you don`t hit the server, it`s not ajax call. So you have to provide ALL the options before and then do client side javascript lookup for values that match.
However if you want to update jsf component i think it will be an ajax call anyway there in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

As Oskars Pakers suggested, without visiting the server side you won't be able to do any AJAX. Solution in your case would be to put all the data on client side in `<option>` tags. This however could be very slow to load depending on how much data you have and would make your server generate unnecessary code if user does not need it. If you still decide to do it, your best option to emulate autocomplete behaviour on client side is to use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), they have also brillinant, build in AJAX functionality if your boss changed his mind.

Comment: Can we use this component strictly with AJAX and bound the values to backing bean.

Comment: yes, this is how I am doing it via `<p:remoteCommand>` Take a look at the Rotten Tomatoes example